# R: Compute max of next 12 hours for each timestep

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe `df <- tibble(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2), v= c(0, 3, 1, 2), time = c(as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 12:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 20:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 3:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2016-12-01 12:30:00")))`

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
     id   v time               
  <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>             
1     1     0 2016-12-01 12:30:00
2     1     3 2016-12-01 20:30:00
3     2     1 2016-12-01 03:30:00
4     2     2 2016-12-01 12:30:00
```

For each timestep and within each `id`, I want to compute the max value of `v` within a specific time period, e.g. `12 hours`. My solution is the following:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(max_in_12h = purrr::map_dbl(time, function(t){max(v[time >= t && time <= t + 60*60*12])}))

     id   v time                max_in_12h
  <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                   <dbl>
1     1     0 2016-12-01 12:30:00          3
2     1     3 2016-12-01 20:30:00       -Inf
3     2     1 2016-12-01 03:30:00          2
4     2     2 2016-12-01 12:30:00       -Inf
```

However, in my experience, `purrr` scales poorly when the dataframe has millions of rows. Is there another neat option?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to test whether the performance is adequate but here is an alternative.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.*, max(b.v) as max
  from df a
  left join df b on a.id = b.id and 
  b.time > a.time and b.time <= a.time + 60 * 60 * 12
  group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
  id v                time max
1  1 0 2016-12-01 12:30:00   3
2  1 3 2016-12-01 20:30:00  NA
3  2 1 2016-12-01 03:30:00   2
4  2 2 2016-12-01 12:30:00  NA
```